# Listar duas tabelas relacionadas PrimeFaces x Hibernate

Tags: java, java-ee, primefaces, eclipse, hibernate

Estou precisando listar informações do duas tabelas no mesmo grid, elas possuem relacionamento criado pelo próprio hibernate.
Precisaria do nome do fornecedor na tabela exibida a baixo

No caso seriam essas classes:

**Modelo:**

```
public class Produto {

@Id
@GeneratedValue
private Integer id;
private String nome;
private String marca;
private String categoria;
private double preco;


@ManyToMany
private List<Fornecedor> fornecedor = new ArrayList<Fornecedor>();

public List<Fornecedor> getFornecedor() {
    return fornecedor;
}

public void adicionaFornecedor(Fornecedor fornecedor) {
    this.fornecedor.add(fornecedor);
}

@ManyToMany
private List<Produto> produtos = new ArrayList<Produto>();

public List<Produto> getProdutos() {
    return produtos;
}

public void adicionaProduto(Produto produtos) {
    this.produtos.add(produtos);
}


public Produto (){
}
  /*getter and setters*/
```

---

```
@Entity
@Embeddable
public class Fornecedor {

@Id
@GeneratedValue
private int id;
private String nome;
private Integer telefone;
private String email;


@ManyToMany 
private List<Fornecedor> fornecedores = new ArrayList<Fornecedor>();

public List<Fornecedor> getFornecedores() {
    return fornecedores;
}

public void adicionaFornecedor(Fornecedor fornecedores) {
    this.fornecedores.add(fornecedores);
}

/*getter and setters*/
```

---

```
<p:dataTable value="#{produtoBean.produtos}" var="produto" 
paginatorTemplate="{CurrentPageReport}  {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {PageLinks} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink}"
paginator="true" rows="5" style="margin-bottom:10px">
    <p:column >
        <f:facet name="header">Nome</f:facet>
        <h:outputText value="#{produto.nome}" />
    </p:column>
    <p:column>
        <f:facet name="header">Marca</f:facet>
        <h:outputText value="#{produto.marca}" />
    </p:column>     
    <p:column>
        <f:facet name="header">Categoria</f:facet>
        <h:outputText value="#{produto.categoria}" />
    </p:column>     
    <p:column>
        <f:facet name="header">Preço</f:facet>
        <h:outputText value="#{produto.preco}" />
    </p:column>     

</p:dataTable>
```

Comment: Suas entidades têm mesmo esses autorrelacionamentos? `Produto` tem `@ManyToMany` `Produto` ? Dá uma formatada melhor nas entidades também, ficou um pouco confuso. Não é possível identificar facilmente o término das classses `Produto` e `Fornecedor`.

Answer (score 0):

```
<p:dataTable value="#{produtoBean.produtos}" var="produto" 
paginatorTemplate="{CurrentPageReport}  {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {PageLinks} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink}"
paginator="true" rows="5" style="margin-bottom:10px">

<p:column>
        <f:facet name="header">Telefone Fornecedor </f:facet>
        <h:outputText value="#{produto.fornecedor.telefone}" />
    </p:column>  
    <p:column>
        <f:facet name="header">Nome Fornecedor </f:facet>
        <h:outputText value="#{produto.fornecedor.nome}" />
    </p:column>  

    <p:column>
        <f:facet name="header">Email Fornecedor </f:facet>
        <h:outputText value="#{produto.fornecedor.email}" />
    </p:column>    

</p:dataTable>
```

Comment: Tenta assim, vamos ver se funciona!